# Как указать путь к Sql файлу что бы он выполнился при миграции?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Cоздаю новое решение которое состоит из двух проектов: Core и WebApi, модель базы данных  и скрипты sql находится в проекте Сore

добавляю миграцию
add-migration -Project Core -StartupProject WebApi

в сгенерированный код миграции добавляю команду выполнить sql

```
migrationBuilder.Sql(File.ReadAllText("MigrationScripts\FileName.sql"));
```

миграцию делаю так

```
update-database -Project Core -StartupProject WebApi
```

на что получаю следующую ошибку

> Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Projects\SolutionName\WebApi\MigrationScripts\FileName.sql'.

Как указать корректный путь к sql скрипту что бы он был доступен в момент выполнения миграции?